# Haskell type family error

Tags: haskell

Sorry to bother you with this simple problem. I'm trying to learn how the type family extension works. When I fool around with it I encountered an error I couldn't figure out why.

```
class Foo a b c where
    data T a b c :: *

    f :: a -> T a b c

    g :: T a b c -> b

    h :: c -> a -> b
    h c a = g $ f a
```

Error message:

```
    Could not deduce (Foo a b c0) arising from a use of ‘g’
from the context (Foo a b c)
  bound by the class declaration for ‘Foo’
  at DB/Internal/Typecast.hs:(17,1)-(25,19)
The type variable ‘c0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  a :: a (bound at DB/Internal/Typecast.hs:25:9)
  h :: c -> a -> b (bound at DB/Internal/Typecast.hs:25:5)
In the expression: g
In the expression: g $ f a
In an equation for ‘h’: h c a = g $ f a
```

I don't understand how is c ambiguous in `T a b c` for `g`. Can't the compiler get the type of `c` from the `T a b c` of `f`?

I just want the composite of `g . f`

Comment: Please fix the indention in your code example - that is, post your actual code. Posting code other than what you're actually using just obfuscates the actual problem.

Comment: "Can't the compiler get the type of `c` from the `T a b c` of `f`?" Yes, but where does `f` get its `T a b c` from?

Comment: @DanielWagner Sorry I dont think i understand how type family works. Isn't the T a b c in both f and g what I declare in an instance declaration using the data key word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in the definition

```
h :: c -> a -> b
h c a = g $ f a
```

there is no restriction that `f` and `g` refer to the *same* instance that you are defining `h` for. (And this flexibility is often useful for defining instances.)

From type inference, the result of `g` is restricted to be of the same type `b`, and the argument of `f` is restricted to be of type `a`, but there's nothing saying that the `T a b c` passed from one to the other is using the same `c`!

To fix this in this case, you can enable `ScopedTypeVariables` and do

```
    h c a = g (f a :: T a b c)
```

Note that this works because data families are "injective" (the type arguments of a data family can be deduced from the final type). If you had used a *type* family instead, even this wouldn't work, since then `T a b c` would not necessarily determine `c` at all.